# Can circularly polarized light induce magnetization?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, polarization

In optics, we usually consider a non-magnetic medium where the magnetization $M$ is zero, while the polarization P is proportional to the electric field $P=\epsilon_0\chi E$. $P$ is induced by some microscopic dipoles with dipole moment $p$. These dipoles would align with the electric field's direction. I wonder if it is correct to assume that the magnetization is always $0$ no matter what kind of light that is sent into the medium. Since for example, if we send a circularly polarized light into the medium, E would rotate, and then the dipole's direction would also rotate, such rotation should create a loop of electric current, and then create an effective magnetic dipole moment, which contradicts our model that the medium should not create any magnetization.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing that forbids optical magnetic permeability in principle but in practice it is extremely rare. I found a paper that claims the only such example. A polarisation dependent case would even be more exotic.

‘ These results demonstrate the only known material with an optical-frequency permeability that differs appreciably from vacuum’.

A moving dielectric should present a non-zero permeability.

https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.127.173604

Comment: How would you classify gyromagnetism (Faraday's polarization rotation) in a medium of having tensor permeability?

Comment: @hyportnex Birefringence is my best guess.

Answer (score 4):

We have the two susceptibility equations:
$$\begin{align}
{\bf P} &=\varepsilon_0\,\chi_e\,{\bf E} \tag{1}\\
{\bf M} &= \chi_m\, {\bf H}. \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
For non-magnetic material we say $ \chi_m=0, $ which means that ${\bf M}$ does not follow the magnetic field with its oscillation frequency. The circular current of your example  would be a constant circular current so it gives a static magnetic field and can not be described simply as a nonzero (possibly complex) value of $\chi_m$. In general, the ability to create a static $B$-field by light is called the [inverse Faraday effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Faraday_effect), whether it is by the mechanism you describe or something else.

There are two reasons why the effect of your example might be weak and therefore perhaps insignificant compared with other causes of the inverse Faraday effect:

1. Quantum mechanics can change the more or less classical reasoning that we use in the description here, like with ferromagnetism (which is classically not possible, but thanks to QM it exists: [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Explanation), perhaps here we could have the opposite...)
2. The polarization ${\bf P}$ represents $+$ and $-$ charges separated to opposite sides. The movement is in the same circular direction for both of them, so the circular currents of the $+$ and $-$ charges will actually have opposite sign! But we can still argue (if QM doesn't invalidate our reasoning) that e.g. due to different mass, the $-$ charges might have a larger displacement from equilibrium than the $+$ charges, so the effect is not ruled out.

Also note that if we would change to linearly polarized light in your example, we would definitely say that a current is induced, since $P$ changes with the frequency of the
light, which is an oscillating current. That's well-known and is simply part of the
[displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current#Explanation), accounted for in the definition of de $D$-field. One could say that this is in favor of your proposed mechanism!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, circularly polarized light (CPL) can give rise to magnetization in some materials. It is referred to as the optical magnetization or optical orientation effect. It is a phenomenon which is caused by a combination of light and magnetic moment of electrons in the material.

**Theory:**

When the circularly polarized light interacts with the material, the magnetic moments (spins) of the electrons are twisted around due to the angular momentum of the light. As a result of the torque, the spins can precess, therefore, the alignment direction of the spin in the light propagation direction. This alignment of spins leads to the formation of a macroscopic magnetic moment of the sample.

**Mathematics:**

Let us define the angular momentum per unit energy carried by the circularly polarized light as $S$. This light will merge together with the magnetic moment $m$ of an electron, it exerts a torque given by the cross product:
$$
\tau = m \times S
$$
Taking for example a whole collection of magnetic moments (for example, spins) inside the material, their total torque results in precession. Thus, at the end of this precession, the spins are aligned.

Mathematically, the induced magnetization $M$ is in accordance with the average magnetic moment per unit volume $m$ of the material:
$$
M = \chi\langle m\rangle
$$
where $\chi$ is the magnetic susceptibility of the material. In the optical magnetization, $\tau$ will depend on several factors, like the intensity, and the light frequency, and the material properties.

Comment: Are you talking about magnetic resonance?

Answer (score 0):

In an electromagnetic field, charges accelerate and experience a magnetic field from their own spins. The magnetic field of the dipole differs from the external field seen by electrons, and this results in a force on the electrons that are also aligned in the dipole's field.
But the net field is zero - and therefore so is its effects.

Answer (score -2):

No.

> Can circularly polarized light induce magnetization?

Light has no magnetic properties. Reference: National Bureau of Standards, Department of Energy.

- Light can be measured for mass and that mass can be determined to some extent.
- Light can be measured for wave length and that wave length can be determined to some extent.
- Light has no magnetic properties and light has no interaction with magnetic anything in any manner.

As to the discussion on optical activity: It has been known and studied and recorded that some chemicals do in fact turn the polarity of some specific wave length light per the distance that the light passes through the optically active chemical, and with consideration of the density of the chemical being passed through.

Back to the question:

> Can circularly polarized light induce magnetization?

Light can not be circularly polarized. Polarization per light wave is in a singular plane. Many light waves with various planes of polarity (single to each) should not be referred to as circularly polarized as that is a invalid description.

In the instance of a singular light wave passing sufficiently through an optically active chemical, if that light wave turns an entire 360 degrees then it at any one time has still a singular plane of polarity albeit changing via the passing through the medium. But, it is not ever in thus having a circular polarity.

The short answer is "no."

A long answer with some explaining I have given.